# JavaScript bookmark with keyword no longer working in Firefox 68

Tags: firefox, javascript, google-search

I have a Firefox bookmark set up for searching the current site, with location `javascript:{location.href="http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:"+window.location.hostname+"%20%s"};` and keyword `cs`. Typing "cs test" while on the domain `http:\\example.com` would take me to `https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site:example.com%20test`. This feature is extremely useful (and still works in Chrome).

Now, though, the address bar seems to act as though the keyword wasn't set - only showing suggestions from history etc. This also applies to several other JavaScript-based bookmarklets I was using.

Is there a workaround for this? Is this an intentional change by Mozilla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same question and (big) problem after restarting after update/s. Firefox(FF)65 to 68... Search-bookmarklets (rightclick item: `add keyword for this search(bar)`) could display fine incl after removal of `%s` (url) bit but that one often-needed bookmarklet that kept keyboard-triggering, never displayed in url-dropdown despite toggling off both search and history results (`alt-t -> options -> search`), and affixing with `*` quick-filter (for url-dropdown) etc. Tried entirely recreating, removing dupes and etc but nope.

Remembered reading somewhere about buggy keywords duplication or defining-persistently if changed after changing, in `places.sqlite` (file) but needed a sql-reader (for database-files) to filter out exact to delete exact etc. Obviously not gonna go so far for such a simple bug so.. Several recent-history deletes and today, several deletions of X-sqfiles later, found an X-update/s changed the aforementioned files contents. It no longer holds bookmarks themselves, just browsing history.. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite (says seamonkey but seems to incl firefox too).

So re-eimported `bookmarks.html` and re-tested keyworded to realise it was only all bookmarks(url `location`) starting with `javascript:`

Thus refined search again, leading to these:
013: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3052138
019: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1552141
08?: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.filter.javascript

1 ***Default/true to `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` (in `about:config`) will filter OUT js-bookmarks.***
Toggled it here and alls displaying again. Browser restart not required. ..Except the js/bookmarkelt itself isnt running. Restarted browser also and.. nope.
2 ***Set `browser.urlbar.quantumbar` to false as well and restart..*** Yep, finally. Enjoy! If that worked for you too.

### --------------------

WHAT IS `QUANTUMBAR`?
Supposedly removes/adds something cool/better (idk, speed? design? ux?) to search+location hybridisation (`awesomebar`2.0?) but (so far) toggling it OFF is the answer to many many "new bugs" circa FF56.. Fancy rename courtesy of browser-rename which you may have ignored/forgotten back when FF first rolled out speed-updates and displayed a newly-installed yay-page everytime browser was restarted. One of them redubbed its entire browser, redirected a few install/yay/doc pages or something to the like.
017: https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2017/11/14/introducing-firefox-quantum/

> The address bar in QuantumBar gets a bit bigger when it is selected or when a new tab page is opened. This is a simple but effective visual indicator that the bar is selected. The dynamic list of suggestions and one-off searches with alternate search engines will now be quite smaller in width. In other words, the suggestions would take up the same width as the address bar.

... cannot remember but newtab now (after steps above) doesnt resize url-bar, thats true. url-bar still selects as colored glow-border and dropdown styling (eg., background color) still works regardless..

> Up until recently, Firefox forgot what the users have typed if they clicked outside of the area or switched tabs accidentally. The new QuantumBar will display the last state automatically. This will allow users to resume instantly from where they left off accidentally.

After toggling+restart, still able to ctrl-z through tab/typing history..

> The new address bar comes with one-off search icons apart from the preferred search engine. These icons will now come with descriptive text that mentions the searches conducted by clicking them are for a single use or search only. In other words, using them won’t alter the default search provider in the Firefox browser.

Still displaying the whole gamut of `search for X with:` and text-altering (eg.,`Search Wkipedia (en)`) icons here.. Moreover (somewhat related), the auto-jump (relocation) to populate url-bar when typing query into searchbar inside newtab page/s, remains.?

019: https://appuals.com/mozilla-firefox-gets-new-quantumbar-address-bar-design-and-method-to-confuse-advertisers-by-polluting-user-tracking-data/